# Install multiple facebook applications simultaneously

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We're using the facebook SDK to install multiple facebook applications simultaneously, but sometimes not all apps are installed.
It appears there is some limitation or bug regarding the number of facebook applications we can install at a time (on facebook's side).

For the time being we've implemented a workaround, which includes waiting for a few seconds between each app installation, but obviously that's not a solution and it's also not working properly.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? What did you do with it?

Thanks!

Relevant Installation Code:

```
 FB.api('/'+pageId+'/tabs?access_token='+pageAccessToken, 'post', params,
```